# What is the difference between Java Garbage collection and C++ object destruction?

Tags: java, c++, garbage-collection, destruction

I read somewhere that Garbage collection is not like destruction(in the C++ sense). how they are different?

Comment: There are lots of sources for information on how Java garbage collection works. Some are very detailed down to the algorithm level and some are aimed at the programmer. Google is your friend.

Comment: @Lee: While there is a lot of information on how GC and C++ destructors work, it may not be so simple to get a high level description of the key advantages and disadvantages of each one of the approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ destruction is deterministic, garbage collection is not.

In C++ you can guarantee when destructors will be called, in Java there is no such guarantee at all. In fact, your destructors might never be called in Java.

Comment: but destructor's don't do the same thing as garbage collection.

Comment: @Caesar Nobody said they do.

Comment: @delnan The answer suggests that they do

Answer (score 2):

- Destructor is called before an object is about to be deleted (Whether it is on the stack or heap)
- Garbage collection will go through your program every now and then checking to see if there are any variables that are no longer being used and delete them